# Detect drag event on window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Im trying to figure this out like desperate but I couldn't come up with the right way.

Im trying to offer users the ability to change the background picture by drag-and-drop a picture into the browser. However, I can't be able to detect the drag events properly. when using

```
$(window).on 'dragenter', (e) =>
  console.log e.target
$(window).on 'dragleave', (e) =>
  console.log e.target
```

I always get the events triggered on individual DOM elements but never on the window/body itself, meaning if my DOM elements/container/wrapper dont cover the whole window, it does not work properly. I know it's possible since GMail can make it work somehow, but I seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you need to bind the events to $(document). Because of event propagation, everything should eventually bubble up to document. If you only want the dragging to work for a specific part of the page, try using classes/class selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I binded it to both window/document and body as it should bubble up. However, the problem is that it doesn't do that seemingly. The Problem also is that even if I get the dragleave event, the target is never the body/window it self, so I can never know when it actually leaves the window, right?

Comment: Hm... that's odd. It should bubble up. Are you using any stopPropogations? Those sometimes mess up event bubbling. What do you mean the target isn't in the window? It seems like to be that you could simply use e.target...

Comment: yeah im using jquery and check e.target as shown above, but it never bubbles up ... I imagine soemthing on my site is capturing and preventDefaulting, but i dont have any other listeners registered on these events ...

Comment: As I read [here](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag), none of the drag events bubble.